# Cannot apply style for custom edit text

Tags: java, android, material-design

I'm trying to apply TextInputLayout theme programmatically to create a custom edit text once and use it anywhere.

This is my Custom edit text class:

```
package com.enjoyapps.weddingapp.view;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper;

import com.enjoyapps.weddingapp.R;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;

public class CustomEditText extends TextInputLayout {


    public CustomEditText(Context context) {
        super(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox));
        init();
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
//        super(context, attrs);
        super(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox), attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox), attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setBoxStrokeColor(Color.BLUE);
        setBoxCornerRadii(50,50,50,50);
        setBoxBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    }
}
```

As you can see, in Constructor I'm setting the style with :

```
new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox)
```

And when i add the custom edit text to xml , it's not getting the attribute that I set in init method.

But when I apply the same theme in xml, it's working and getting the all attribute from init method.

```
<com.enjoyapps.weddingapp.view.CustomEditText
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</com.enjoyapps.weddingapp.view.CustomEditText>
```

Comment: If an answer works for you, it is important to accept it. It also rewards you with some reputation points!

Answer (score 1):

Which style using your app?
Just add to your main style:

`<item name="editTextStyle">@style/YourStyle</item>`

Example:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
   <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
   <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

   <item name="editTextStyle">@style/YourStyle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This would work if it wasn't `TextInputLayout` because `TextInputLayout` is not related to `EditText`. What is needed is `textInputStyle` instead of `editTextStyle`. But there's also a `style` you have to apply to the `TextInputEditText`.

Answer (score 1):

It took a bit of digging to find out the problem. Apparently, `TextInputLayout` uses a `boxBackgroundMode` in order to use certain attributes from different styles.

In addition to `ContextThemeWrapper`, you have to set the `boxBackgroundMode` for your `TextInputLayout`.

> Therefore, if you are using :
>
> - `FilledBox` : you need to use `BOX_BACKGROUND_FILLED`
> - `OutlinedBox` : you need to use `BOX_BACKGROUND_OUTLINE`

In your case, just add `setBoxBackgroundMode(BOX_BACKGROUND_OUTLINE)` into your `init()`:

```java
private void init() {
    // ... some styling here

    setBoxBackgroundMode(BOX_BACKGROUND_OUTLINE);
}
```