# Android attribute works only from style?

Tags: android, xml, styles

I have textinputlayout and want to add an attribute to it but it work only when assigned from style

my style

```
 <style name="round_text" parent="Base.Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout">
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox</item>
</style>
```

my view with style

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_input"
    android:theme="?attr/textInputStyle"
    style="@style/round_text"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

my view without style and attribute assigned directly

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_input"
    android:theme="?attr/textInputStyle"
    android:editTextStyle="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: My answer should explain exactly why it is not working. I hope you find it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as `@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox`.

There is, however, the `@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox` style for the `TextInputLayout`.

> The attribute you assigned directly was `TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox`. **It should be `TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox`**
>
> Please Note that there is no `editTextStyle`. The reason it was being applied from your `style` is because `round_text` had the `parent="Base.Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout"` which by default uses the `TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox` as `style`.

---

According to the [Material Design Docs](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/), you should do the following:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_input"
    android:theme="?attr/textInputStyle"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it really helped me alot but i have noticed weired thing that this style works only with style but not with theme 

        android:theme="@style/round_text"
could you please explain it to me?

Comment: Alright, so `TextInputLayout` and `TextInputEditText` are both Custom Layouts. And your `theme` : `@style/round_text` is attempting to change `editTextStyle`. But the `editTextStyle` only affects the style of the `EditText` and not the `TextInputLayout` (which is in fact getting the borders around it and everything ). You don't have a way to set the `style` of the `TextInputLayout` because it is a custom view. So you will have to set it from the xml.

Comment: Can you give me an example of those attributes?

Comment: this is my style now

<style name="round_text" >
        <item name="boxBackgroundMode">outline</item>
        <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@null</item>
        <item name="boxCollapsedPaddingTop">0dp</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">?attr/colorControlActivated</item>
    </style>

as you notice i removed the parent style and it works as required when used in style attribute not theme

sorry for annoying you with all this stuff but i'm trying to understand style and theme

Comment: Alright, check this [Developers Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes). Also, because those attributes apply to the whole theme. It does not know which element to specify it to I believe (such as using `editTextStyle` to indicate the style of an `EditText`). In addition, creating themes for Custom Views is a bit different, [check this](https://infinum.com/the-capsized-eight/how-to-support-themes-in-custom-views-for-android-apps). You aren't annoying me at all, I am not quite knowledgeable about those myself, so I am learning too :)

Comment: Thank you alot you did helped me alot .
I was trying to answer this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59918896/cannot-apply-style-for-custom-edit-text)
and found myself asking another question so trying to answer question made me dig deeper and learn new things.
Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for your questions :)